# Identifying difference among column names within a list of dataframes and changing them to have similar column names for all dataframes

Tags: r, data-management

In my working directory I have 100 csv files saved in data folder. (each of these dataframes have 200 variables and supposed to have same variable name) I tried to check the column names of these csv files- whether they are same or not. I did the followings-

```
dt_paths <- dir_ls(path = "data", glob = "*.csv")
map_chr(dt_paths, ~read_lines(.x, n_max = 1))
unname(map_chr(tri_paths, ~read_lines(.x, n_max = 1)))
table(unname(map_chr(dt_paths, ~read_lines(.x, n_max = 1))))
```

I find not all the data files have same column names(96 have similar column names and 4 has different column names).

My objective to

1. identify which files have different column names and
2. Then change those 4 files column names to similar names of other 96 files column names.

Is there any nice handy way of doing that?

Comment: Are you trying to name the columns based on `table` output i.e. `tbl1 <- table(unname(map_chr(tri_paths, ~read_lines(.x, n_max = 1)))); nm1 <- scan(text=names(tbl1)[which.max(tbl1)], what = ""); map(tri_paths, ~ read_csv(.x) %>% setNames(nm1))`